# Trouble finding element with cssSelector having parameters at end of URL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a link in my application as mentioned below:

```
<a title="xyz" href="abc/home?locale=en"> some text </a>
```

I wrote a cssSelector to get this element.
`a[href*='home?locale=en']`
The problem is that this css selector works fine in Firebug, Firepath and Chrome console. However it does not identify element(s) with Selenium WebDriver i.e. `By.cssSelector("a[href*='home?locale=en']")` does not work.

I identified that character `?` is the problem. However I do not know how can I bypass it.

Comment: Your issue is probably not the `?` but the quoting. Try this instead: `By.cssSelector("a[href*='home?locale=en']")`

Comment: Sorry, that is not the problem. Edited the question.

Comment: I just tried the exact same link with the Chrome driver and it worked as expected.

Comment: I found the root cause. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was that my server is appending a jsessionid after the href. The jsessionId is not shown appended on the browser side.

href during System.out.print
`https://abc/home;jsessionid=3213323123123AAA3232?locale=en`

Same href on browser side: 
`/abc/home?locale=en`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `href` with cssSelector, use `By.linkText()` or `By.partialLinkText()` to identify the element. try the below selector.

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText('some text'))
```

Comment: My link text is dynamic and entered by the customer. Therefore, it is not of much help.

Comment: Then can you try using XPath like `.//a[@href="abc/home?locale=en"]`.

Comment: I tried that too but same issue. I found the root cause and posted it as an answer.